# How to load the data into Solr from Kettle.?

Tags: solr, kettle

Is there any way to load data into Solr from Kettle.?
I have tried some plug ins, but it does not seems to be working..

I want to index the data into Solr from Kettle. I want to give input as file/table/csv and output as Solr.. How this can be done.?

I have completed creating custom plugin to load the data into Solr. But, the problem now is, the HttpSolrServer class i have used is accpepting SolrInputDocument with one field only. Its throwing no such method error if the document has more than one field.

Comment: What plugins have you tried and what do you mean by 'not working'. I.e. please post error messages.

Comment: Hi Brian.. I have followed instructions from Kettle plugin developement and written custom solr plugin. It came into output palette. But data is not being indexed. Do you want me to share the source.? I have Meta, OutputData and Output implementing the required interfaces...

Comment: I see; it's a custom plugin. What is the failure mode? By not being indexed, I assume you mean nothing is loaded into Solr, but no error message, correct? I have no experience with Solr, so sorry if these questions seem basic. How does you plugin work? Does it read files and write directly to Solr, or does it put data into a data flow? Maybe sharing the source is a good idea.

Comment: Hi Brian.. I have moved bit more ahead in the plugin.. Now i am facing a weird problem.. I have used HttpSolrServer class to load the Index data. The problem is, it is accepting SolrInputDocument with only one field. If there is more than one field, its throwing exception saying method not found.. :'(

Comment: The code is working in stand alone java mode without any bit of issues.. But, its happening in kettle only.. I can attach my custom plugin if you want to have a look...

Comment: The plugin picks up fields and parses them and creates a String in required format in Output class and calls load method in Meta. The Meta gets the string and loads the data into Solr with the help of HttpSolrServer.

Comment: Go ahead and attach the plugin if you like. Again, I know nothing about the Solr API, but the exception makes me wonder if it's a problem with method overloading. Maybe you need to call the method once for each field instead of supplying multiple fields? Have you tested it with multiple fields in the straight Java version?

Comment: Hi Brian. Sorry for the delay.. Out of station for last two days. I have created Gist and saved the code in GitHub.. You can find the classes @ https://gist.github.com/srini-daruna.. As i said, The problem is more related with Solr..

Comment: Hi Brian... The plugin is working fine now.. I made a mistake that is mother of all stupidity.. I have built and used solrj package of 4.1 instead of 4.4... I somehow overlooked it and thought 4.1 is latest.. but, got to know it today...

Comment: Thanks for your responses all the while.. Thank you.